# problems with the 2 options joption

Tags: java, swing

I'm having problems with these 2 different options, the first one opens up just fine to a browser for future use, but the second option opens the browser and not the dialogue in which i'd like to have open. Also can someone tell me how to make the cancel button cancel out and not open the browser, thanks in advance here's the code.

```
    public static void CheckForUpdates(){
Object[] possibleValues = { "Check for Updates", "Check for version ID" };
Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
"What would you like to do?", "",
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);
if ( JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
       try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.google.ca"));
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
    }
    if ( JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "version ID: V1");
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing constants is deterministic, i.e. you don't get any variation in behavior.

You need to check the result of `showInputDialog` which is an `Object` value. The value is `null` when nothing (cancel) is selected.

```
if (selectedValue != null) { // anything selected?
    // Check for version ID?
    if (selectedValue.toString().equals(possibleValues[1])) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "version ID: V1");
    } else {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.google.ca"));
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Aside: Java naming conventions show that method names start with an *lowercase* letter such as `checkForUpdates`.